# Did 20th-century Marxists acknowledge that the "social science" predictions of Marxism were wrong?

Tags: marxism, economics, history

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKMwJo9DHUQ), starting at 5:36, Stephen Hicks claims that there are three central "social science" Marxist predictions, which I would sum up as follows:

Over time, in any capitalist society,

1. The share of the population in the lower class will increase,
2. The share of the population in the middle class will go to zero,
3. The number of people in the upper class will converge towards a very small number.

He then goes on to say

> " ... even in Marx's lifetime, and certainly in the succeeding generations of Marxists, by the time we get to 1900, right, 1920, and so forth ... all three of those predictions failed - it's not just that they failed by a little bit or that the data was mixed, but that all of the data is showing that the exact opposite is coming to pass. [...] Social science stands on its predictions as measured by the data, and by every measure, Marxist social science failed to fit the data, in fact the data was the exact opposite. And this caused a crisis not only by people who are not sympathetic to Marxism ... but a crisis within Marxism. What you find when you read the Marxists of each succeeding generation is that they are aware of the data: we predicted this, but now the data says that."

Now I believe that the above is likely to inspire a lot of politically motivated debate, so I'd like to clarify the scope of my question: In the first half of the 20th century, did Marxists acknowledge that the social predictions of Marxism had failed and that the predictions did not fit the data?

---

Remark: I originally [posted this question on Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41833/did-20th-century-marxists-acknowledge-that-the-central-social-predictions-of-mar), but it was recommended to me to also ask here.

Comment: This is a very good book, Page Smith, The Progressive Era and WWI.https://www.amazon.com/007-America-Peoples-History-Progressive/dp/0070585733 what happened in the USA with Wilson and WWI, happened with Friedrich Ebert and the SDP in Germany. The Frankfurt School later set out to answer the question, What happened?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how all of that relates to my question. Are you basically saying that the Frankfurt School are the successors of 19th century Marxists? What was their stance on the "science-y" (falsifiable) statements of Marxist theory?

Comment: Here is Horkheimer later on:  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OBaY09Qi-w0  The body of Marx's works, his writings, have an interesting history themselves. They are now in the Netherlands. https://socialhistory.org/en/news/marx-engels-papers-completely-available-online  You can also study the work of Maximilien Rubel. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximilien_Rubel

Comment: Don't you want to write up an answer? I'd gladly accept it. The video with Horkheimer is on point!

Comment: Thanks, but what Horkheimer said was probably not the complete answer, that you will have to decide. That is why I also referenced the work of Rubel. If you go to his Wikipedia article there are some external links and you read some articles by Rubel if you wish, you can at least get some idea of the "time delay" in understanding exactly what Marx himself wrote. If you have at least some idea of this problem (in other words that we are still learning about Marx) then this may give a better understanding of the issues.

Comment: For instance you will see in writings about Marx the words "Marxian", and "Marxist". The people who use "Marxian" generally have a better idea that it took a while to get a grip on what Marx wrote, what he believed, etc. || As with many things, there are different opinions on this subject and I don't know "the answer" myself.

Comment: <In the first half of the 20th century, did Marxists acknowledge that the social predictions of Marxism had failed and that the predictions did not fit the data?>..i have info about  five points in  world of 2014..on which marx's analysis came true...but your restriction of time period forbids me...

Comment: As I stated in another thread about this topic here: The very nature of the method he outlines in his work undercuts any notion of a strong concept of prediction. Everything uttered at an abstract level (such as a tendency or law) is 1) conditional and 2) determined at the level of concrete singularities first, not the opposite approach of historical economics of assuming the abstract (or ideal). An analysis is made from data collected, if future data contradicts the prior you update your assumptions. Materialist analysis isn't afforded a separation from that exposure to data.

Comment: The fact that you have people like Hicks making this argument but you have many others making the complete opposite argument tells me that quite a few people misunderstand how to approach and contextualize Marx's analyses: https://www.theguardian.com/news/2018/apr/20/yanis-varoufakis-marx-crisis-communist-manifesto

Comment: @ClearMountainWay my question is not "Was Marx right?" but rather "Did 20th-century Marxists believe Marx wasn't right?", put simply. Undeniably, one of the pillars of modern social science is that theories regarded as scientific should predict measured data.

Comment: The fact that people make contradictory arguments from the same starting point leads me to different conclusions: 
1) Marxist theory is not scientific because it admits a variety of interpretations that leads to a variety of different outcomes 
2) Different outcomes are due to misunderstandings of the original work, indicating bad scholarship on the part of the interprets as a whole

Comment: @user159517 " one of the pillars of modern social science is that theories regarded as scientific should predict measured data" Unless I misunderstood your question, you've asked about Marx, not with "social science" which means you have to start with what he set out do and how it differed from the economists of his day that he was working against or alongside. Social science as it's invoked today has nothing to do with political economy as he understood it.

Comment: RE: "Marxist theory is not scientific". This is an interesting historical topic. If you were to thumb through any of Marx's works and then thumb through the works of Engles in later life, you see a very clear effort of the latter to "scientifize" dialetical materialism. One can understand Engels's effort by contextualizing it to the intellectual climate of that era, but it is quite distinct from how Marx himself described both his methodology and his intentions in analyzing economic "law" and "tendency".

Comment: Regardless of the wildly varying poles of 20th century reception, if we look at Marx's actual writings on his method (appndx to the Kapital book I or earlier in the Econ and Phil Mans of 1844), it becomes clear that the indeterminacy of present/future is never viewed as a matter of predictive value of data. That would be to ignore his entire critique of Hegelian determinism. The role of conscious activity and subjectivation is from even early on central to the SHAPING of present. This leaves a very specific framing of the analysis of economic trends and raises the import of conditions.

Comment: @ClearMountainWay well, I think you misunderstood my question. My question is independent of Marx' original intentions - it is about whether 20th-century Marxists believed that Marxism as social science had failed. The video with Horkheimer posted by Gordon above gives some indication that this was indeed the case.

Comment: Ok gotcha. But understand that Horkheimer statement isn't in any way a consensus view. See also I. Wallerstein, E. Balibar, T. Eagleton, P. Anderson, A. Negri, D. Harvey etc for completely different takes.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom note that my question is not about whether the predictions *are* wrong, but whether early 20th-century Marxists *believed* they were wrong. If you read the last paragraph of my question, you'll also see that I was asking about the first half of the 20th century, so what's happening today in the US is out of scope.

Comment: This is maybe late, but e.g. in Germany there was a "revisionism debate" around 1900 (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduard_Bernstein) where people considering  themselves Marxists (the SPD) discussed precisely this and what to learn from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1 The share of the population in the lower class will increase.
>
> 2 The share of the population in the middle class will go to zero.
>
> 3 The number of people in the upper class will converge towards a very small number.

Horkheimer can hardly be made in stand in for '20th-century Marxists', whatever his views, acknowledgements or revisions.

But let's take the predictions.

**The share of the population in the lower class will increase.**

Is **the** 'lower class' a Marxist term ? Marx refers to 'the proletarian class', 'agricultural labourers', 'the lumpenproletariat', 'the unemployed'. He offers specific predictions for each of these, not for 'the lower class'.

If we make these distinctions, it does appear quite definitely that Marx predicted that the share of the population in the 'lower class' will increase. He says that all landowners will eventually disappear, that the feudal aristocracy will be destroyed by foreign competition, and that entire sections of the ruling class will be drawn into the proletarian class.

**The share of the population in the middle class will go to zero.**

Marx thinks this will happen along two routes : (a) the smaller capitalists or bourgeoisie will 'go under' to the larger under the impact of competition, and (b) the bourgeoisie will be eliminated as a class in the proletarian revolution.

So : another authentically Marxist prediction

**The number of people in the upper class will converge towards a very small number.**

Marx predicts that joint-stock companies will emerge as the new aristocracy, that the moneylending class will disappear, that all landowners will also disappear, and that larger capitalists will absorb or put smaller capitalists out of business. That indicates a relatively small 'upper class'.

**Was the failure of these predictions acknowledged by 20th-century Marxists ?**

I'm not at all dismissive of Horkheimer but it would be interesting if we could add to the number of Marxists who were clear-sighted enough to perceive that something had gone wrong with Marx's predictions.

I add just one point, though. Marx does refer on occasion (e.g. in Capital, I) to 'the iron laws of history' but in more reflective moments he recognised that his 'laws' were not inevitabilities but actually 'trends'. This claim is supported by the following quotation :

> "He [my critic] feels himself obliged to metamorphose my sketch of the genesis of
> capitalism in Western Europe into an historico-philosophical theory of the *marche
> generale* imposed by fate on every people, whatever the historic circumstances in which
> it finds itself, in order that it may ultimately arrive at the form of economy which will
> ensure, together with the greatest expansion of the productive powers of social labor,
> the most complete development of man. But I beg his pardon. (He is both honoring and
> shaming me too much.)"
> Marx to the Editor of a Russian Joumal, 1877: Correspondence of Marx and Engels,
> ed. by Dona Torr (Intemational, 1934), p. 35. (Cited in Richard Hudelson, 'Popper's Critique of Marx', Philosophical Studies: An International Journal for Philosophy in the Analytic
> Tradition, Vol. 37, No. 3 (Apr., 1980), pp. 259-270 : 270.)

Marx and Marxists can reasonably argue that given that Marx was arguing from trends and not laws, his projection of predictions from trends doesn't disprove the trends; it just shows the specific predictions were wrong or ill-timed. In other words, the failure of Marx's predictions doesn't refute his laws since despite his occasional language he formulates no laws strictly speaking.

Eduard Bernstein realised that Marx's predictions were failing : Selected Writings of Eduard Bernstein, 1900–1921. Prometheus Books, 1996. Rosa Luxemburg in The Accumulation of Capital ([1913] 1951) also could see that revisions were needed. George Lukacs's History and Class Consciousness ([1922] 1971) rejected the idea of laws of development and recognised that Marx's trends could not support specific predictions, at least those that Marx had made. Finally in this brief survey Antonio Gramsci emphasised the need as he saw it for a political party, not a class-conscious proletarian class, to overturn the ideological hegemony of the capitalist class. Gramsci wrote in the wake of the rise of fascism in Italy; in a fascist prison he was sure that Marx had miscalculated the likelihood and power of proletarian class-consciousness and that the interventions of Mussolini's *fascisti* would block Marx's predictions, indeed had blocked them and would continue to do so until a communist party could emerge with the strength and determination to rival and overturn the fascist party. See  Gramsci, Antonio, 1971, Selections from the Prison
Notebooks. New York: International Publishers.

**Reference**

A wider survey and longer list of Marx's social science predictions is offered in Fred M. Gottheil, Marx's Economic Predictions, Evanston : Northwestern University Press, 1966.